# How to manage more than one UIImageView in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I wanna to create dynamically `UIImageView` on every tap on main view and also wanna to move all the created `UIImageView` by finger movement.I've got success to dynamic creation on every touch my code is below :

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint pt = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    imgView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(pt.x,pt.y, 100, 100)] autorelease];
    imgFilepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"img" ofType:@"png"];
    img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imgFilepath];
    imgView.tag=i;  
    [imgView setImage:img];
    [img release];
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
}
```

Now I wanna to move any of the dynamically created `UIImageView` by finger movement on it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the userInteractionEnabled property of the UIImageView to yes in the method you create it (i. e. the method you posted):

```
imgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

then you will most probably need to subclass UIImageView and implement the following methods to move your image view around:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

Hint: in the touchesMoved: etc. method, you'll want to track where the user's finger moved -- after reading some more docs you'll most probably end up using `-[UITouch locationInView:]` -- you'll need to convert the coordinates to the superview of your image view and then move the image view itself in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In `touchesBegan` detect the `imageView` you have touched. In `touchesMoved` move the selected `imageView` by setting it's center to the touch point moved.